# covering map arrow

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I am trying to draw an arrow going down similar to these we usually see in topolgy books. For example, when we study covering spaces we usually put the covering space and then an arrow and then the base space.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Here is a picture:]

Comment: A simple down arrow is just `\downarrow`? Without an image of what you are looking for it is difficult to help you further. For complicated diagrams you should look into `tikz`.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: Are you interested in a "symbol" that you could use in inline text? Or are you interested in using this as a graphic in an image? For example, consider the multitude of different notations/forms available from the [Wikipedia entry on Covering Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I support the use of TikZ for diagrams, but if you are looking for something slightly simpler, you could try the `amscd` package.

`@>>>` and `@VVV` make right and down arrows, respectively. You can also use `@<<<` and `@AAA` for left or up arrows. The arrow labels go between the first and second characters or between the second and third characters, depending on whether you want them above/left or below/right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amscd}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{CD}
    E @>\tilde{f}>> F\\
    @V\pi_{E}VV @VV\pi_{F}V\\
    M @>>f> N
  \end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pretty quick option using `tikz`

[image: screenshot]

Note in particular the use of the `positioning` library, which allows you to specify `node`s in terms of relative positions to other `node`s- see Section 5.2 of the `tikz & pgf` documentation for more details. I also set the arrows as `stealth` which is short for 'stealth fighter jets'.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% set arrows as stealth fighter jets
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (E) at (0,0) {$E$};
    \node[right=of E] (F) {$F$};
    \node[below=of F] (N) {$N$};
    \node[below=of E] (M) {$M$};
    \draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] {$\tilde{f}$};
    \draw[->] (F)--(N) node [midway,right] {$\pi_F$};
    \draw[->] (M)--(N) node [midway,below] {$f$};
    \draw[->] (E)--(M) node [midway,left] {$\pi_E$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old fashioned way with Xy-pic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
  E \ar[r]^{\tilde{f}} \ar[d]_{\pi_{E}} & F \ar[d]^{\pi_{F}} \\
  M \ar[r]_{f} & N
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html is what i refer to for this stuff; there are example outputs linked to the page