# Isomorphisms in commutative diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sorry for the basic question. I am trying to get commutative diagrams like

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
$$\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{A & B \\
C& D \\ };
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$\widetilde {f} $} (m-1-2)
(m-2-1) edge node[auto] {$ f $} (m-2-2);
\draw[double equal sign distance,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] (m-1-2) -- (m-2-2);
\draw[double equal sign distance,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}$$
```

My question is: How do I replace the vertical equal sign connecting `$A$` to `$C$` with a vertical isomorphism sign, a vertical version of `$\simeq$` or `$\approx $`?

Comment: possible duplicate: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43641/covering-map-arrow/43644#43644](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43641/covering-map-arrow/43644#43644)

Comment: Sort of vaguely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15830/86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to modifiy your code, but it only resulted in weird shifting and not the desired result at all. As an OCD like control freak, I always position "by hand", so tell me if this works for you:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (2,0) {B};
\node (C) at (0,-2) {C};
\node (D) at (2,-2) {D};
\draw (A) edge node[above] {$\widetilde {f} $} (B);
\draw (C) edge node[above] {$f$} (D);
\draw (A) edge node[above,rotate=90] {$\simeq$} (C);
\draw (B) edge node[above,rotate=90] {$\approx$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** With some "cheated" changes as *wh1te* proposed:

```
\draw[white] (A) edge node[rotate=90,black] {$\simeq$} (C);
\draw[white] (B) edge node[rotate=90,black] {$\approx$} (D);
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** Of cause, one would still see the lines on a non-white background, so this should be better:

```
\draw[transparent] (A) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {$\simeq$} (C);
\draw[transparent] (B) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {$\approx$} (D);
```

---

**Edit 3:** I could not think of any automated way right now, but you could use a `\resizebox`:

```
\draw[transparent] (A) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {\resizebox{1.5cm}{0.3cm}{$\simeq$}} (C);
\draw[transparent] (B) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {\resizebox{1.5cm}{0.3cm}{$\approx$}} (D);
```

[image]

Comment: My understanding was that he wanted the actual line connecting the two nodes to be like that symbol, not just label the existing line. So a `snake` decoration could probably be used to do the job.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tom.  I am happy to learn of how to do this too.  But I was preferring as whlt3 suggested, to be able to make the whole line connecting the two nodes as the isomorphism sign

Comment: This is almost what I had in mind, but can you make the isomorphism signs fill the space between the nodes more, like the double equals sign does in my example.

Comment: Possible instead of `resizebox` : ` \path (C) -- node[sloped,transform shape,inner sep=0pt,xscale=6] {$\simeq$} (A) ;   `

Comment: Where are the arrows? It's impossible to see the "directions".

Comment: Don't the functions have a direction? E.g. in the diagram you can't see whether $f$ is from $C$ to $D$ or the other way around.

Comment: No, e.g. two functions are isomorph if they are reversible, so if at all you'd put arrow tips to both ends.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use tikz-cd for commutative diagrams. Here is how I am indicating isomorphisms.
[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand*{\isoarrow}[1]{\arrow[#1,"\rotatebox{90}{\(\sim\)}"
]}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow{r} & A \arrow{r} \isoarrow{d} & B \arrow{r} \isoarrow{d} & C \arrow{r} \isoarrow{d} & 0 \\ 
0 \arrow{r} & A' \arrow{r} & B' \arrow{r} & C'  \arrow{r} & 0 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for horizontal or diagonal isomorphisms. I hope someone will figure out a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I took this from a style for Subseteq to be vertical or horizontal.

```
\tikzset{cong/.style={draw=none,edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$\cong$}}},
         Isom/.style={draw=none,every to/.append style={edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$\cong$}}}}}
```

Load the code in the preamble, then in `tikzcd`

```
$\begin{tikzcd}
\ker(f)\arrow[hook]{r}&B\\
A\arrow{ur}{i}\arrow[Isom]{u}
\end{tikzcd}$
```

It seems to work well for me.

Comment: This is great!  To make the arrow appear, remove `draw=none` and add `above` instead.  To flip the label so it appears on the other side, add `rotate=180` to the list inside the square brackets.